# Lenovo Y510p Upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, lenovo-laptop, hardware-rec, ramdisk

I am in the process of replacing my main HDD with a 250gig SSD, I will then mount the original HDD in the Ultrabay using a HDD Caddy.

I am also wanting to upgrade the RAM of my laptop to 8gigs because of the relatively large Engineering programs I have been using in my final year so far.

The system currently has 4gigs of RAM and on the Lenovo website I found the following:

> Up to 16GB DDR3L- 1600Mhz(Support Dual Channel) [1 SODIMM slots
>   (1x2GB/1x4GB/2x2GB /2+4GB/2x4GB/1x8GB/4+8GB/2x8GB)]

I would just like to check if the best way to upgrade would be to use 2x4GB or 1x8GB, im not sure what the different combinations entail.

Comment: Better to go with 1 x 8 GB if you want to save for a future upgrade. The Dual Channel Performance can be compromised for a better save, in my opinion. But as Frostalf pointed there is good output with Dual Channel and they need to be identical even to the latency values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to go with 2x4GB. If you go with the 2x4GB configuration. Your system could take advantage of the Dual Channel. Which doubles the memory bandwidth. Also note, to take advantage of the Dual Channel, both ram cards need to be identical in specs.